# Disable javascript for some parth of my page

Tags: javascript

How can I disable javascript for some  part of my page. For examle I have next structure

```
html
 head
  my js files
 head

 body
  div
   my components(they use javascript)
  div

  div
   some untrusted content(may be some elements with javascript triggers 'on load' or smt. like that
  div 
 body
html
```

I don`t want to process this content and only give it 'AS IS' but dont be vulnerable for XSS attack.

**update**
I want to build small service for posting text information from simple form and saving to the database. And I want to show it for user in preview mode on the html page(include two elements - header and body ).

Comment: It really depends on where the content is coming from, and how it is coming in. Can you please include that in your post. Otherwise there is no clear way to answer this question.

Comment: that untrusted content needs to be sanitized before it ever gets to the html in browser. You can't stop a script tag from executing. Not nearly enough information given for source of the content

Comment: charlietfl, oh.... it is bad news, but its still fine. I can process it before save to the database

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the `<`'s in your untrusted content with `&lt;`'s:

```
var somewhatSanitizedContent = untrustedContent.replace("<", "&lt;");
```

This should make all HTML tags appear as plain text, disabling `<script>` tags as well.

However, it may be a good idea to sanitize your input before storing it, instead of after.